# is there anyway to crop image without capturing it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, camera, ocr

I am working on an application where I need to make live OCR in flutter like this one https://drive.google.com/file/d/1trdAavzY8MStk1ytlEqmvmZtHyzjG2vi/view?usp=sharing , how to achieve this?
i wanna crop a portion in live camera as per in a video

I am able to get text from an image but not from live camera

Comment: [flutter_scalable_ocr](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_scalable_ocr) will help you

Comment: Thanks for you response, as per flutter div, the size of the box is fixed, the corners of the size box can't be changed by the user, but I wanna make it changeable